Change the size of a button of a specific page on Next.js using tailwind css
I have a button component set to a spefic size, but i want the button to be bigger on this page,how can i do it?
<div>
<h1 className="font-bold text-[25px]"> Voce deseja acessar:</h1>
<div className="flex justify-center space-x-10"> 
<Link href='/farmacia/medicamentos' className='py-10'>
    <MyButton buttonText='Medicamentos'/>
</Link>
<Link href='/farmacia/registros' className='py-10'>
    <MyButton buttonText='Registros'/>
</Link>
<Link href='/farmacia/fichasmedicas' className='py-10'>
 <MyButton buttonText='Fichas Médicas'/>
    </Link>
<Link href='/farmacia/itens' className='py-10'>
    <MyButton  buttonText='Itens'/>
</Link>
<Link href='/farmacia/vacinas' className='py-10'>
    <MyButton buttonText='Vacinas'/>
</Link>

This is the code of the butto component
export function MyButton({ buttonText, buttonType }: IButtonProps){
return(
<>

{buttonText}

</>
)
};

I think addng text-lg or text-xl or text-2xl (or more xl) too the className list in your Link should do the trick
